# "Encapsulation helps make sure clients have no dependence on the choice of representation"

Tags: java, encapsulation

I am familiar with the concept of encapsulation. However, recently I have found the following statement regarding encapsulation (which is according to the author correct):

**Encapsulation helps make sure clients have no dependence on the choice of representation**

Could you please give me a hint what is meant by **clients** and the **choice of representation**. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

What the author is trying to explain is the fact that encapsulation allows you to modify the inner representation of the data in some without have any side effect in the clients. The clients could be any other classes that are using yours, and the choice of representation the way you decide to store the data in your class.

As an example, imagine that you have a class where you store the Employees of some Company. It could be something like this:

```
public class Company {
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(String employeeId) {
        //search for employee
    }
}
```

You store the employees of the company in a List, and provide two methods, one that retrieves all the employees, and another that searches for a given one. Some day you realize that maybe a Set or a Map would be a better structure to store the Employees, and you decide to refactor the code. As long as you have provided methods to retrieve the information of the employees, instead of giving direct access to the "employees" structure, you could change the implementation of these functions to fit with the new definition of your class and your clients wouldn't notice those changes.